# How to prove $||P_\Omega(v)-P_\Omega(u)|| \le ||v-u||, \forall u,v \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: inequality, convex-geometry, projection

Suppose $\Omega$ is a closed convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $P_\Omega(u)$ represent the projection of $u$ onto $\Omega, \forall u \in \mathbb{R}^n$. That is to say $P_\Omega(u)= \underset{v \in\Omega}{\operatorname{argmin}}||v-u||$ for some norm $||\cdot||$. For your convenience, you may think $||\cdot|| $ as Euclidean norm.

How to prove $||P_\Omega(v)-P_\Omega(u)|| \le ||v-u||, \forall u,v \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Similar to a question I asked, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3097393/show-that-the-projection-moves-you-closer-to-the-set-i-e-p-cx-y-leq-x

Comment: @TonyS.F. Thanks, I do understand your question and the solution you provide, but I still cannot find any close relation between these two problems. Could you give me a hint, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finished this proof by myself. The proof is a little bit tricky and requires some computation. I wrote it on my iPad so I hope it does not affect the readability.[image: Proof_Part1][image: Proof_Part2]

I am not a native English speaker so if there are some grammar mistakes or wrong terms, you are welcome to correct them. BTW, you are also welcome to replace the pictures with Mathjax and Markdown.